# How to print an Object and its all fields by hierarchy using reflection

Tags: c#, object, circular-dependency, system.reflection

I need to write a utility in C# using reflection that when given an object- prints in order of hierarchy all of the properties in the object.
I wasn't familiar with reflection so I don't know how to use it, but the instructions are to use reflection.

it's important to avoid circular dependency when object A contains object B, and object B contains object A. (Thought to use in Map to avoid this, print the object only if the Map didn't include it and then insert it to the Map).

Comment: We can _help_ you with homework, but we aren't going to to it for you. Start by getting the object's type (with `typeof` or `GetType`) then get the type's properties `GetProperties`. A property has a _getter_ and a _setter_ (no need for the setter). They act like methods that can be _Invoked_. The way to figure out Reflection is to write your code one or two lines at a time, and see what you get in the Debugger. Use lots of temporary variables so you can see what's going on (in the debugger). Good luck

Comment: If you want just print you can serialize it using any json serializer, it will inspect hierarchy for you https://dotnetfiddle.net/bx9Dni

Comment: Thank you! I'll do it right now. The function GetProperties is exactly the direction I was looking for

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.